# Parameter comparison in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've created the following stored procedure that accepts 2-parameters. Is there a way to compare the parameters against specific columns in the tables? Basically want user to input proj_num and newDate and if they are in the tables display some info.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE empInfo2 
(
     @proj_num AS char(3)
    ,@newDate AS smalldatetime 
)
AS
BEGIN
/* Insert IF Statement here Intent is to display an ERROR message
if the proj_num and/or date are not within the tables*/

IF (@proj_num <> /*Compare to PROJ_NUM column to see if number is in range*/
    OR /* I assume @newDate must be compared to ASSIGN_DATE?? */ )
    PRINT 'Invalid input. Enter correct Project Number and Date.'


SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMP_NUM
      ,EMPLOYEE.EMP_FNAME
      ,EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME
      ,PROJECT.PROJ_NUM
      ,ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGN_DATE

FROM   ASSIGNMENT INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE ON
       ASSIGNMENT.EMP_NUM = EMPLOYEE.EMP_NUM INNER JOIN
       PROJECT ON ASSIGNMENT.PROJ_NUM = PROJECT.PROJ_NUM

WHERE  PROJECT.PROJ_NUM = @proj_num AND ASSIGN_DATE = @newDate  
END
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: If the data isn't in the table, the select will return zero rows. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Required to display an error to screen if no rows match. Used similar statements in another procedure that works fine. This one is a little different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF (@proj_num NOT IN (SELECT ...)) OR (@newDate NOT IN (SELECT ...))
    PRINT 'Invalid input. Enter correct Project Number and Date.'
```

Answer (score 0):

it can contains some syntax errors but the idea is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE empInfo2 
(
     @proj_num AS char(3)
    ,@newDate AS smalldatetime 
)
AS
BEGIN
/* Insert IF Statement here Intent is to display an ERROR message
if the proj_num and/or date are not within the tables*/

   IF ( NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM PROJECT WHERE PROJ_NUM = @proj_num
                               AND ASSIGN_DATE = @newDate ) 
    BEGIN
       PRINT 'Invalid input. Enter correct Project Number and Date.'
    END
   ELSE

  SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMP_NUM
  ,EMPLOYEE.EMP_FNAME
  ,EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME
  ,PROJECT.PROJ_NUM
  ,ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGN_DATE

  FROM   ASSIGNMENT INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE ON
     ASSIGNMENT.EMP_NUM = EMPLOYEE.EMP_NUM INNER JOIN
      PROJECT ON ASSIGNMENT.PROJ_NUM = PROJECT.PROJ_NUM

  WHERE  PROJECT.PROJ_NUM = @proj_num AND ASSIGN_DATE = @newDate  

  END
```